# What is the minimum set of types required to compile `async` code?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, async-await, infrastructure

Out of curiosity, I'm trying to get some simple `async`/`await` code to compile under .NET 3.5 Client Profile:

```
async void AwaitFoo()
{
    await new Foo();
}

class Foo
{
    public IFooAwaiter GetAwaiter() { … }
}

interface IFooAwaiter : System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion
{
    bool IsCompleted { get; }
    void GetResult();
}
```

I'm perfectly aware that .NET 3.5 does not support this language feature, as expressed by this compilation error:

> *Cannot find all types required by the `async` modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?*

I am also aware of the [NuGet package `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), which does not have support for .NET 3.5.

**Question:** What is the **minimum set of types & type members required for `async`** code to compile? Is this minimal set officially documented; and if so, where? (Note that I'm only interested in successful compilation, not execution.)

---

**What I've got so far:**

I've been trying to find this minimum set of types by experiment, which appears to be possible since the compiler reports required, but missing types one by one:

> *Predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine` is not defined or imported.*

Defining the reported type according to MSDN reference pages then leads to the next missing type being reported. I have so far:

- `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine`
- `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion` (required by the example code above)
- `System.Threading.Tasks.CancellationToken` (required by `Task`)
- `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions` (required by `Task`)
- `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`

At this point I stopped, since `Task` has lots of members, but the compiler does not report exactly which members it requires; it just reports the type as a whole. I might therefore reproduce much more of the type definition than what is actually needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've determined by experiment that the following types are sufficient in order to make the C# 5 compiler process basic `async`/`await` code (even when targeting .NET Framework version 2!):

- [`IAsyncStateMachine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.iasyncstatemachine.aspx)
- [`INotifyCompletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion.aspx) (no member declarations needed)
- [`ICriticalNotifyCompletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.icriticalnotifycompletion.aspx) (no member declarations needed)
- [`AsyncVoidMethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncvoidmethodbuilder.aspx)
- [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder.aspx)
- [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138506.aspx)
- [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) (no member declarations needed)
- [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) (no member declarations needed)

The most minimal declarations for these that I've found to be acceptable to the C# compiler follow below.

```
namespace System.Threading.Tasks
{
    abstract class Task { }
    abstract class Task<TResult> : Task { }
}

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    interface INotifyCompletion { }
    interface ICriticalNotifyCompletion { }

    interface IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        void MoveNext();
        void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine);
    }

    struct AsyncVoidMethodBuilder
    {
        public static AsyncVoidMethodBuilder Create() { … }
        public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
            { … }
        public void SetResult() { … }
        public void SetException(Exception exception) { … }
        public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) { … }
        public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            // where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
            { … }
        public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            // where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
            { … }
    }

    struct AsyncTaskMethodBuilder
    {
        public Task Task { get { … } }
        public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            // where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
            { … }
        public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            // where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
            { … }
        public static AsyncTaskMethodBuilder Create() { … }
        public void SetException(Exception exception) { … }
        public void SetResult() { … }
        public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) { … }
        public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) 
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
            { … }
    }

    struct AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>
    {
        public static AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult> Create() { … }
        public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) 
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine 
            { … }
        public void SetResult(TResult result) { … }
        public void SetException(Exception exception) { … }
        public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) { … }
        public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            // where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine 
            { … }
        public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            // where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
            // where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine 
            { … }
        public Task<TResult> Task { get { … } }
    }
}
```

(I am throwing a `NotImplementedException` wherever it says `{ … }`.)

Answer (score 8):

In terms of the C# compiler, you also need:

- [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder.aspx)
- [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138506.aspx)
- [`AsyncVoidMethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncvoidmethodbuilder.aspx)
- [`AsyncStateMachineAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncstatemachineattribute.aspx)
- *Possibly* [`ICriticalNotifyCompletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.icriticalnotifycompletion.aspx) although I believe that' just used by the builder.

I wouldn't *expect* that either `TaskCreationOptions` or `CancellationToken` would actually be required - I can't think where they'd be used in the generated code.

Fundamentally though, you really need the whole TPL support for it to work - just having it *compile* isn't going do it for you. If you're only interested in this for curiosity, that's a different matter. You might be interested in my [Eduasync](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx) blog series, which was a crude version of getting the CTP release of the compiler to work without the `AsyncCtpLibrary.dll` assembly (against .NET 4.0) - basically supplying all the relevant types.

The [source code](https://code.google.com/p/eduasync/) won't work against the C# 5 compiler as things changed a bit for the final release, but most of the concepts have stayed the same.

Comment: Thanks. Did you find out about the types in your list yourself, or did you take the list from official documentation? -- Thanks also for the Eduasync link, I've already started reading these blog articles.

Comment: @stakx: Well I initially built up the list as I went along and implemented bits of Eduasync - but now I'm looking back on the types that I know the compiler uses in the generated code.